# PlotArea colour change with python pptx

Tags: python-3.x

I want the plot area color to be changed in the pptx chart. Please help.

Code snippet which i have tired,

```
*graphic_frame = slide.shapes.add_chart(XL_CHART_TYPE.COLUMN_CLUSTERED, x, y, cx, cy, chart_data)
chart = graphic_frame.chart
shape_properties = OxmlElement("c:PlotArea")
chart.element.append(shape_properties)
fill_properties = OxmlElement("a:solidFill")
shape_properties.append(fill_properties)
rgb_color = OxmlElement("a:srgbClr")
color_value = dict(val='%02x%02x%02x' % (222, 235, 247))
rgb_color.attrib.update(color_value)
fill_properties.append(rgb_color)*
```

Answer (score 1):

Made few changes in code snippet.It should work with as below.

```
plot_area = graphic_frame.chart._element.chart.plotArea
shape_properties = OxmlElement("c:spPr")
plot_area.append(shape_properties)
fill_properties = OxmlElement("a:solidFill")
shape_properties.append(fill_properties)
rgb_color = OxmlElement("a:srgbClr")
color_value = dict(val='%02x%02x%02x' % (222, 235, 247))
rgb_color.attrib.update(color_value)
fill_properties.append(rgb_color)
```